# protection from sql injection with GET parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I know that this question has been asked so many times but there are a lot of different answers that's confusing me. I have just one parameter that's passing through url and it is in a sql query, so a GET request and i really don't know how to protect myself from SQL injection. How can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: That's simple. Don't think of GET request at all - it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think that it's too much code... I wrote this question because I think that using PDO is not the only right way

Comment: alas, you are wrong. prepared statements is the only right way. And PDO is among the easiest to use.

Answer (score -1):

```
$var = mysql_escape_string($_GET['your_param']);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: FYI, the mysql extension is now deprecated (I did not downvote though).